# Progressive Web APP (PWA) - Magento 2.2.2 Not working

Tags: magento2.2.2, pwa

I am using Magento 2.2.2.

I have configured Progressive Web App [PWA](https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/progressive-web-apps-magento-2/) in my Magento Site. It is working fine in development server. Not working in Live Server. Both Servers having HTTPS. But, live server HTTPS is running in the particular port.

When I checked in mobile, in both live and development server popups are coming. but, I configured as `fullscreen` app, but it is opening in browser tab.

How to solve this. Is that issue came because of HTTPS running in port? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decreased the firebase version to 4.12.0 from 4.13.0, it is working now.